# welcome.Show() - converting to c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I have a small vb.net program that works.  I want to convert a few vb.net lines in a Module to c#.  The lines of code are:

```
  Dim welcome As New WelcomeScreen(True, "http://www.trade-ideas.com/cms_static/ChannelBar/channelbar.html")
  welcome.Show()
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain better what do you want?

Comment: There are some [online converters](http://converter.telerik.com/) that can accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WelcomeScreen welcome = new WelcomeScreen(true, "http://www.trade-ideas.com/cms_static/ChannelBar/channelbar.html");
welcome.Show();
```

Comment: @Gopi what's the difference from my answer?

Comment: Welcome. If it works,make the answer as useful. so others can get through that answer

Comment: @jack.the.ripper There is no difference. Actually we both posted at the same time with milliseconds gap. That's it.

Comment: but I don't get it? why answer with the same answer from another user?

Comment: Because you were typing at the same time.

Comment: @jack.the.ripper 48000 milliseconds, ample time to copy/paste/post. ;)

Answer (score 1):

First you'll have to understand the mechanics behind c#, yes you can translate it directly but you should learn the syntax first.

```
WelcomeScreen welcome = new WelcomeScreen(true, "http://www.trade-deas.com/cms_static/ChannelBar/channelbar.html");
welcome.Show();
```

at the end classes are classes, the same with instances or any other objects.

Comment: there  you go, try it out!

Answer (score 0):

You can find Language converter tool on Visual Studio gallery. Here is the link: 
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/cc8da841-f978-4c3e-8397-c820bd57298c

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fab9aebd-a821-4480-b79f-73722535b3e4